# Why isn't javax.activation in the java source zip?

Tags: java, ubuntu

elsewhere eg.[1] it is explained that when you install the java source in 
ubuntu, it is put here: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/src.zip

The problem is that it does not contain the javax.activation package
and thus not classes like: javax.activation.DataSource 
Why isn't it there?
Must I download the source manually to get that?

[1] [Where to find Java JDK Source Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896727/java-jdk-source-code-where-to-find-it)

Answer (score 2):

The package is `javax.activation`, not ***java.activation*** - and typically, source code for `javax...` packages isn't included.

Comment: +1: Not all Java "base" classes are `java.`, some are `javax.`

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the subject, I fixed it now.
I'd like to see the source of all the classes that comes with the jvm in eclipse, so its a bit annoying that only some of them is in the java-source package.
Is the only way to do this to manually download the sources?

Answer (score 0):

The various components of `javax` use different licenses, so this *could* be the reason. I've taken the liberty to ask your platform of choice's maintainers [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/+question/164047).

I will update this answer as soon as I get an answer.