# Where does Java keep standard library classes?

Tags: java

Where does Java keep standard library classes like java.util.* on the hard drive under Windows OS?

Comment: If you're looking for the source, it's online.

Answer (score 12):

> When you say
>
> import java.util.Date;
>
> you are not reading a file. You are telling the compiler to treat the
>   type reference "Date" as if it was "java.util.Date".
>
> When the compiler later resolves java.util.date it will find it **in the
>   JDK's jre/lib/rt.jar** file.

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t125842-re-newbie-q-where-is-java-util.html

Answer (score 4):

**If you are looking for the source code, you can find the source code online as described here:**

[Where to find Java JDK Source Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896727/java-jdk-source-code-where-to-find-it)

**Additionally, you can find it within the src.zip file:**

E.g. my own computer this is the:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\src.zip
```

**The actual compiled classes are contained with the **lib/rt.jar** file that the compiler and jvm uses.

Answer (score 1):

In the JDK1.X.X... directory there is a zip file named src.zip. unzip it and have a look. you might want to make a copy of it and move it to another directory before you do it.