# Non-blocking socket hangs while reading when it shouldn't

Tags: java, sockets, nio, nonblocking

I have the following code. And you can see its output below. As I think by javadoc `socket.read` should never hang or whatever and this is an unexpected behavior.

```
    Context con = new Context();
    con.buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    log.trace("reading.. {}, {}, {}, {}, {}", socket.isConnected(), !socket.isBlocking(), socket.isOpen(), socket.keyFor(selector).isReadable(), socket.keyFor(selector).isValid());

    FutureTask<Integer> readTask = new FutureTask<Integer>(

            new Callable<Integer>() {

                Context con;

                Callable<Integer> setContext(Context con) {
                    this.con = con;
                    return this;
                }

                public Integer call() throws Exception{
                    int rd = socket.read(con.buf);
                    return Integer.valueOf(rd);
                }

            }.setContext(con)
    );

    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    exec.submit(readTask);

    int read = 0;
    try {
        read = readTask.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        log.error("hello java");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

(I do not need a futuretask there at all, but it was just to check my assumption about stucking in `socket.read` method).

And here's the log output (notice that `!socket.isBlocking()` is reversed, so it's showing it's in NON blocking mode):

```
reading.. true, true, true, true, true
hello java
```

this means after 5 seconds we still got nothing, socket is still opened, and nothing that could be wrong.

Please help me with that issue. Could it be something around socket's "keepalive" or OS or java or firewall (still I'm reading and writing at localhost only) issue?

This is how I got this socket:

```
SocketChannel socket = ((ServerSocketChannel) key.channel()).accept();
log.trace("accepted:{}", socket.getRemoteAddress());
socket.configureBlocking(false);
socket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
```

Comment: You should show where you create the socket

Comment: I've added that to the question body.

Comment: Are you calling `read()` on this channel from anywhere else?

Comment: On some of the channels, that were created exactly like that.

Comment: This could be your problem... From the Javadoc:  If another thread has already initiated a read operation upon this channel, however, then an invocation of this method will block until the first operation is complete.

Comment: Have you stepped through this code in a debugger?

Comment: @Tim is correct, `read()` is not even being called here

Comment: No, I'm sorry that was the old version of code. I could either update the output with the values that println printed, but just removed printlns. It certainly does call `socket.read()`. And the issue appears only after 30-40 connected normally.

Comment: Then see my above comment about doing a `read()` from the same channel in multiple places

Comment: @crocboy I've marked the thread name with a timestamp so I could see that there were no other thread (just to be sure, at first I knew there were no other thread) and `socket.read` is being called only there. There's no other `read` usage. May the same thread block?

Comment: I'll ask it again: "Have you stepped through this code in a debugger?"  With a debugger, you should be able to see what's going on within the `socket.read()` call, which will let you see (for example) if you're getting held up by an if statement about another thread having an in-progress read, or whatever.

Comment: *Why* do you have the following code? If you want asynchronous I/O, it already exists.

Comment: You say you see this after 30-40 successful connections.  What happens to your `SocketChannel` and your `Socket` between connections?  Do you reuse them, build new ones each time, etc.?

Comment: @Tim in this case it's new socket channel per new client and channels are not being reused. There are 2 problems with debugging: 1) it's sun.nio.. class, so no source provided 2) my code is a part of web application on tomcat, I'm going to make a simpler version of it, without web context.

Comment: You can download OpenJDK source JARs as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896727/where-to-find-java-jdk-source-code.  If you're using [WTP](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-wtp), you can debug webapps running on your local Tomcat.  (WTP will also let you automatically deploy code to your local Tomcat, which is really useful during development.)