# Built in classes in Java

Tags: java

Java contains many built in classes. I seeked someof them in the Java API documentation but I couldnt see or find the body of these classes and their related methods.

For example when I seeked the clearRect method of the graphics glass I found just the informations as follows without much details.

```
> public abstract void clearRect(int x,
>              int y,
>              int width,
>              int height)
```

Clears the specified rectangle by filling it with the background color of the current drawing surface. This

> operation does not use the current paint mode. Beginning with Java
>   1.1, the background color of offscreen images may be system dependent. Applications should use setColor followed by fillRect to ensure that
>   an offscreen image is cleared to a specific color.
>
> Parameters: x - the x coordinate of the rectangle to clear. y - the y
>   coordinate of the rectangle to clear. width - the width of the
>   rectangle to clear. height - the height of the rectangle to clear. See
>   Also: `fillRect(int, int, int, int), drawRect(int, int, int, int),`
>   `setColor(java.awt.Color), setPaintMode(), setXORMode(java.awt.Color)`

Is there any way to find the source code of these classes ? Or are they hidden by the constructors of Java for some reasons ?

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896727/where-to-find-java-jdk-source-code

Comment: what details are you looking for by chance?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/java2d/SunGraphics2D.java#2363

Answer (score 0):

Download the Java jdk. The source code is in src.zip. Alternatively check this link out:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Class.java