# logic of java in-built method

Tags: java, string

can anyone tell me , where can I find the logic of java in-built String methods like `length()` , `tocharArray()`, `charAt()` , etc... I have tried decompiler on `String.class` but found no logic their. 
I want to a code to count the number of characters of a String without using any in-built String class but I am unable to crack the idea of how to break String into set of characters without using String in-built method..
e.g. `String str = "hello";`
how to convert this String into

```
'h' ,  'e' ,  'l' , 'l' , 'o'
```

and this is not any homework assignment...

please help
with regards, 
himanshu

Comment: http://grepcode.com/search/?r=repository.grepcode.com$java$root&start=0&query=string&entity=type

Comment: The sources are in src.zip inside the JDK directory.

Comment: actually your IDE should be able to show you the code. For eclipse press ctr + left mouse on the `String` - class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896727/where-to-find-java-jdk-source-code

Answer (score 1):

Built-in libraries source code is available with JDK.

The JDK folder would contain `src.zip` which contain the sources for the built-in libraries.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I always used http://grepcode.com. It usually has source code of methods/objects I'm looking for. 
Here is GC for String class [String.length()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.length%28%29)

EDIT:
As for your second question, how to calculate String length. I would use String.toCharArray(). I hope you can calculate length of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Whole string data is kept in a private char `array` field.

`length()` is just:

```
  public int length()
  {
       return this.value.length;
  }
```

And `charAt(int)` isn't much more complicated:

```
public char charAt(int paramInt)
{
    if ((paramInt < 0) || (paramInt >= this.value.length)) {
      throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(paramInt);
    }
    return this.value[paramInt];
}
```

The method you are looking for separation String chars is `toCharArray()`

If you want to decomplie `.class` files try using: http://jd.benow.ca/
It has both GUI application and Eclipse IDE plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can view OpenJDK source code [online](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share). Make sure you're looking at the right version of the code (library version and revision).

For example, here's the code of `toCharArray()` of jdk8:

```
public char[] toCharArray() {
    // Cannot use Arrays.copyOf because of class initialization order issues
    char result[] = new char[value.length];
    System.arraycopy(value, 0, result, 0, value.length);
    return result;
}
```

Here's `charAt(int index)`:

```
public char charAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= value.length)) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
    return value[index];
}
```

You can find the source code of `String` class [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java).

Answer (score 0):

You can't work with a `String` without using - directly or indirectly - its methods. For example, you can iterate over string characters using `charAt(int index)` or create a `StringBuilder(String s)` (which calls `String.length()` internally).