# Get complete JDK source code in IntelliJ or other IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

My IDE is really good about finding the corresponding Java source code for JDK classes. For example, I can open `java.lang.String` in my IDE and see the actual Java source code. However, when I try to open `sun.net.www.http.HttpClient` (which is included in the Java SDK), my IDE just shows me the decompiled `.class` file, which is difficult to read.

My IDE on macOS is looking for the source code in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/src.zip`, and if I unzip that archive I can find `String.java`, but `HttpClient.java` is nowhere to be found. So it makes sense that my IDE can't find it.

Where can I get the complete JDK source code?

Comment: If you use Intellij, and your project is using maven (or similar) for dependencies, it can automatically download sources, just as it can download the api-docs, where available.

Comment: @emanciperingsivraren I regularly do this for Java libraries, but IntelliJ has special handling for the JDK itself, and the Oracle JDK provides only some of the JDK source code.

Answer (score 7):

If you're on Linux, you may be able to find a more complete source code archive at the [OpenJDK Project](http://openjdk.java.net/). However on macOS and possibly other platforms, here is a method that worked for me:

### Download the complete Java source code from Github

```
git clone https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk.git
cd jdk
git checkout jdk8u/jdk8u/master    # For Java 8
```

### Find the Java package you're interested in

```
find . -name HttpClient.java       # Or whatever class you want
./src/share/classes/sun/net/www/http/HttpClient.java
```

Here you can see that `sun.net.www.http.HttpClient` is in the `sun` package, which is located in the `src/share/classes` directory.

### Make a new source archive with the package in it

```
mkdir ~/java
# Replace path below with location of JDK on your machine
unzip /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/src.zip -d ~/java
cp -r ./src/share/classes/sun ~/java
```

## Rebuild the archive and put it back

```
cd ~/java
zip -r src.zip *
cp src.zip /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/src.zip
```

You may have to restart your IDE, but now it should be able to find the previously missing source code.

Comment: A better way to get the source code goes here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896727/where-to-find-java-jdk-source-code) sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-source

Comment: @ChaojunZhong That only installs src.zip which is what he already has.