# How can we edit Java built-in classes such as Java.util.Scanner?

Tags: java, oop, java-6

Just for the sake of curiosity , I want to know  is there a way I can edit/modify Java core classes inside rt.jar. I am searching everywhere in the internet but got no relevant answers. I have also referred to Covert Java(book) but I am unable to understand it.

Note: I don't want to distribute my app. I just want to do it for my curiosity.

Comment: Technically yes, it's possible. But it involves advanced things, so why do you think you need to modify the standard JDK classes?

Comment: You can download the JDK source code and play with it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896727/where-to-find-java-jdk-source-code

Comment: A person who is planning to modify JDK classes is not supposed to be confused about where to find the source code ;)

Comment: Can someone please write the complete steps or make a tutorial on YouTube

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another answer suggested patching rt.jar
I believe this is not the best approach - you effectively cannot distribute your app (unless you have your app contenerized and you deliver Java with your app).

The way to go is to learn about [bootstrap classpath](https://riptutorial.com/java/example/20114/the-bootstrap-classpath)
This should cover most of reasonable use cases.

> The normal Java classloaders look for classes first in the bootstrap classpath, before checking for extensions and the application classpath. By default, the bootstrap classpath consists of the "rt.jar" file and some other important JAR files that are supplied by the JRE installation. These provide all of the classes in the standard Java SE class library, along with various "internal" implementation classes.
>
> Under normal circumstances, you don't need to concern yourself with this. By default, commands like java, javac and so on will use the appropriate versions of the runtime libraries.
>
> Very occasionally, it is necessary to override the normal behavior of the Java runtime by using an alternative version of a class in the standard libraries. For example, you might encounter a "show stopper" bug in the runtime libraries that you cannot work around by normal means. In such a situation, it is possible to create a JAR file containing the altered class and then add it to the bootstrap classpath which launching the JVM.

Comment: I want to know how to patch rt.jar . I don't want to distribute the app . I just want to see how it works.

Comment: Please write the steps to patch rt.jar

Comment: See answer by @Kudin

Answer (score 2):

Better approach would be extending those Class and modifying the specific methods. This will not affect other project where you just wanted Java provided Class

Comment: I am not working on a project. I just want is there a way to patch rt.jar

Answer (score 1):

Files in that jar are compiled .class files from .java source files. You cannot modify the binaries directly that easy, but if you have a source code (e.g. https://github.com/openjdk/) you can compile your own .class files and replace, since JAR is basically an archive with binaries.

Not the most scalable approach, but possible.

Comment: Are you talking about rt.jar

Comment: well, any jar really

Comment: A .jar file is just a .zip file, so you can edit it with tools like 7-Zip.